# Passing Reactive Input into axis of a plotyly chart in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, plotly, shiny-server

I am currently trying to a shiny app that outputs the summary of a simple linear regression and a graph. For both scenarios I would like the user to select the independent and dependent variables from the columns of the table and use those same inputs to run the regression and graph. Right now I can't figure out how to pass the user selected input into plotly for a display. Can anyone assist, thanks in advance!

Here is the sample data:

```
        AvgIR SumCount            AvgLTV     AvgGFEE   AvgRTC       Date
1: 0.04106781   180029 0.753180543134717 0.002424778 319.6837 2015-10-01
2: 0.04036154   160061 0.738038310394162 0.002722529 312.6314 2015-11-01
3: 0.04001407   145560 0.739287372904644 0.002425912 313.0351 2015-12-01
4: 0.04034078   147693 0.739693214979721 0.002600640 315.0238 2016-01-01
5: 0.04055688   142545 0.734515977410642 0.002449523 310.3950 2016-02-01
6: 0.04007467   176344 0.735780463185592 0.002459228 309.9615 2016-03-01
```

Here is the ui:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Regression and Time Series Analysis"), 
  sidebarPanel(
    p("Select a Dependent Variable"),
    selectInput(inputId = "DepVar", label = "Dependent Variables", multiple = FALSE, choices = names(RegData2)),
    p("Select input(s) for the Independent Variable(s)"),
    selectInput(inputId = "IndVar", label = "Independent Variables", multiple = FALSE, choices = list( "SumCount", "AvgIR", "AvgLTV", "AvgGFEE", "AvgRTC", "Date"), selected = "AvgLTV"),
    p("Summary of Regression"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "RegSum")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "IndPrint"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "DepPrint"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "test"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "xaxis"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "yaxis"),
    tableOutput("table"),
    plotlyOutput("graph")
  )
)
```

Here is the server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    lm1 <- reactive({lm(reformulate(input$IndVar, input$DepVar), data = RegData2)})

    Ind <- reactive({input$IndVar})
    Dep <- reactive({input$DepVar})
    plotdata <- reactive({as.data.frame(RegData2[, c(which(names(RegData2) == Ind()), which(names(RegData2) == Dep())), with = FALSE])})

    xaxis <- reactive({names(RegData2)[which(names(RegData2) == Ind())]})
    yaxis <- reactive({names(RegData2)[which(names(RegData2) == Dep())]})

#     xaxisN <- reactive({names(xaxis())})
#     yaxisN <- reactive({names(yaxis())})

    output$table <- renderTable({
      x<-plotdata()
        #RegData2[, c(which(names(RegData2) == Ind()), which(names(RegData2) == Dep())), with = FALSE]

    })

    output$graph <- renderPlotly({

      #xaxis <- paste(input$IndVar)
      #yaxis <- paste(input$DepVar)

      #THIS ONE WORKS, but isn't reactive
      #plot<-plot_ly(plotdata(), x =  ~AvgLTV, y = ~AvgIR, mode = "markers", type = "scatter")

      #THIS ONE DOESN'T WORK, is reactive
      plot<-plot_ly(plotdata(), x = ~input$IndVar, y = ~input$DepVar, mode = "markers", type = "scatter")


    })


    output$IndPrint <- renderPrint({str(Ind())})
    output$test <- renderPrint({str(plotdata())})
    output$xaxis <- renderPrint({xaxis()})
    output$yaxis <- renderPrint({yaxis()})
    output$DepPrint <- renderPrint({input$DepVar})
    output$RegSum <- renderPrint({summary(lm1())})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Not familiar with `, with = FALSE` in the `plotdata` reactive. What is is supposed to do? I get an error on it anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the below answer, your solution worked! The "with = FALSE" for data.tables subsets the data to only those two columns that I have input in the "j" portion of the statement for character values. E.g. [i, j, by]. With the following statement: 
RegData2[, c(which(names(RegData2) == "AvgLTV"), which(names(RegData2) == "AvgIR")), with = FALSE]

it returns this:

               AvgLTV      AvgIR
 1: 0.753180543134717 0.04106781
 2: 0.738038310394162 0.04036154
 3: 0.739287372904644 0.04001407

without the "with = FALSE" it returns position of column headers:
[1] 3 1

Comment: Ok. Just want to point out you can upvote now too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is you can't use variable selectors in plotly, like the `aes_string` function would do for you in ggplot2 - at least the way you tried.

There may be a way to pass character names in plotly, but the docs are really not great and I could find nothing.

However I did make this work - which could be acceptable.

- put the plot dataframe into a local variable df.
- created two new variables xx and yy with the variables to be plotted
- overrode the `xaxis` and `yaxis` labels with the `layout` command.

This made `output$graph` look like this:

```
  output$graph <- renderPlotly({

    df <- plotdata()
    df$xx <- df[[input$IndVar]]
    df$yy <- df[[input$DepVar]]
    plot<-plot_ly(df, x = ~xx, y = ~yy, mode = "markers", type = "scatter") %>% 
                      layout( xaxis = list( title=input$IndVar), 
                              yaxis = list( title=input$DepVar ) )
    plot
  })
```

Yielding:

[image]

Note: Here is how I reformatted and entered the data in case someone wants a repro - took about 5 minutes:

```
AvgIR <- c(0.04106781,0.04036154,0.04001407,0.04034078,0.04055688,0.04007467  )
SumCount <-c(180029 ,160061 ,145560 ,147693 ,142545 ,176344 )
AvgLTV <-c(0.753180543134717 ,0.738038310394162 ,0.739287372904644 ,0.739693214979721 ,0.734515977410642 ,0.735780463185592 )
AvgGFEE<-c(0.002424778 ,0.002722529 ,0.002425912 ,0.002600640 ,0.002449523 ,0.002459228 )
AvgRTC <-c(319.6837,312.6314 ,313.0351 ,315.0238 ,310.3950 ,309.9615 )
Date <- c("2015-10-01","2015-11-01","2015-12-01","2016-01-01","2016-02-01","2016-03-01")
RegData2 <- data.frame(AvgIR=AvgIR,SumCount=SumCount,AvgLTV=AvgLTV,AvgGFEE=AvgGFEE,AvgRTC=AvgRTC,Date=Date)
RegData2$Date <- as.POSIXct(RegData2$Date)
```